# Combining resources into a single binary file

Tags: resources, data-protection

How does one combine several resources for an application (images, sounds, scripts, xmls, etc.) into a single/multiple binary file so that they're protected from user's hands? What are the typical steps (organizing, loading, encryption, etc...)?

This is particularly common in game development, yet a lot of the game frameworks and engines out there don't provide an easy way to do this, nor describe a general approach. I've been meaning to learn how to do it, but I don't know where to begin. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to do this.  m_pGladiator has some good ideas, especially with seralization.  I would like to make a few other comments.

First, if you are going to pack a bunch of resources into a single file (I call these packfiles), then I think that you should work to avoid loading the whole file and then deseralizing out of that file into memory.  The simple reason is that it's more memory.  That's really not a problem on PC's I guess, but it's good practice, and it's essential when working on the console.  While we don't (currently) serialize objects as m_pGladiator has suggested, we are moving towards that.

There are two types of packfiles that you might have.  One would be a file where you want arbitrary access to the contents of the files.  A second type might be a collection of files where you need *all* of those files when loading a level.  A basic example might be:

1. An audio packfile might contain all the audio for your game.  You might only need to load certain kinds of audio for the menus or interface screens and different sets of audio for the levels.  This might fall intot he first category above.
2. A type that falls into the second category might be all models/textures/etc for a level.  You basically want to load the entire contents of this file into the game at load time because you will (likely) need all of it's contents while a player is playing that level or section.

many of the packfiles that we build fall into the second category.  We basically package up the level contents, and then compresses them with something like zlib.  When we load one of these at game time, we read a small amount of the file, uncompress what we've read into a memory buffer, and then repeat until the full file has been read into memory.  The buffer we read into is relatively small while final destination buffer is large enough to hold the largest set of uncompressed data that we need.  This method is tricky, but again, it saves on RAM, it's an interesting exercise to get working, and you feel all nice and warm inside because you are being a good steward of system resources.  once the packfile has been completely uncompressed into it's destinatino buffer, we run a final pass on the buffer to fix up pointer locations, etc.  This method only works when you write out your packfile as structures that the game knows.  In other words, our packfile writing tools share struct (or classses) with the game code.   We are basically writing out and compressing exact representations of data structures.

If you simply want to cut down on the number of files that you are shipping and installing on a users machine, you can do with something like the first kind of packfile that I describe.  Maybe you have 1000s of textures and would just simply like to cut down on the sheer number of files that you have to zip up and package.  You can write a small utility that will basically read the files that you want to package together and then write a header containing the files and their offsets in the packfile, and then you can write the contents of the file, one at a time, one after the other, in your large binary file.  At game time, you can simply load the header of this packfile and store the filenames and offsets in a hash.  When you need to read a file, you can hash the filename and see if it exists in your packfile, and if so, you can read the contents directly from the packfile by seeking to the offset and then reading from that location in the packfile.  Again, this method is basically a way to pack data together without regards for encryption, etc.  It's simply an organizational method.

But again, I do want to stress that if you are going a route like I or m_pGladiator suggests, I would work hard to not have to pull the whole file into RAM and then deserialize to another location in RAM.  That's a waste of resources (that you perhaps have plenty of).  I would say that you can do this to get it working, and then once it's working, you can work on a method that only reads part of the file at a time and then decompresses to your destination buffer.  You must use a comprsesion scheme that will work like this though.  zlib and lzw both do (I believe).  I'm not sure about an MD5 algorithm.

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 2):

do as Java: pack it all in a zip, and use an filesystem-like API to read directly from there.

Comment: This is insecure. The file should be encrypted

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

In Mac OS 6,7,8 there was a substantial API devoted to this exact task. Lookup the "Resource Manager" if you are interested. Edit: So does the [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) physics analysis package.

Not that I know of a good tool right now. What platform(s) do you want it to work on?

---

Edited to add: All of the two-or-three tools of this sort that I am away of share a similar struture:

- The file starts with a header and index
- There are a series of blocks some of which may have there own headers and indicies, some of which are leaves
- Each leaf is a simple serialization of the data to be stored.
- The whole file (or sometimes individual blocks) may be compressed.

Not terribly hard to implement your own, but I'd look for a good existing one that meets your needs first.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I never used the already available tools to do that. If you want to prevent your game to be hacked easily, then you have to develop your own resource manipulation engine.

1. First of all read about [serializing objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(VS.71).aspx). When you load a resource from file (graphic, sound or whatever), it is stored in some object instance in the memory. A game usually uses dozens of graphical and sound objects. You have to make a tool, which loads them all and stores them in collections in the memory. Then serialize those collections into a binary file and you have every resource there.
2. Then you can use for example [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or any other encryption algorithm to encrypt this file.
3. Also, you can use [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) or other compression library to make this big binary file a bit smaller.
4. In the game, you should load the encrypted binary file and unpack it. Then decrypt it. Then deserialize the object collections and you have all resources back in memory.

Of course you can make this more comprehensive by storing in different binary files the resources for different levels and so on - there are plenty of variants, depending on what you want. Also you can first zip, then encrypt, or make other combinations of the steps.

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption algorithm. Read the wikipedia page you linked to. In addition, you should always compress BEFORE encryption, not after. In general, encrypted data is not compressible.

Answer (score 0):

For future people, like me, who are wondering about this same topic, check out the two following links:

http://www.sfml-dev.org/wiki/en/tutorials/formatdat

http://archive.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/pak/