# Game Programming: .DAT file?

Tags: c++, directx

I've seen a lot of games use something similar to a .DAT file or a specific file type that the game has for itself. I'm just beginning with C++ and DirectX and I was interested in keeping my information in something similar to a .DAT.

My initial conception was that it would hold information on the files you wanted to store within the .DAT file. Something similar to a .RAR file. Unfortunately, my googleing skills did not help me in finding the answers.

Right now I'm simply loading textures and sound files from a folder called Data.

**EDIT:** While I understand that .DAT is short for data, and I've found that a .DAT file generally contains any assortment of information, I'm still unsure about how to go about doing something as packing images and sound files into any type of file and being able to read them.

I'm not sure about using fstreams to achieve my task, however I will look into streams related to storing data and how to properly read from that data. Meanwhile if anyone has another answer to offer based on this new information, it would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thanks to the answers, I stumbled across a similar question on stackoverflow and felt I'd share it here. [Combining resources into a single binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205877/combining-resources-into-a-single-binary-file)

Comment: Check out http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/dat I used the keywords DAT and extension on google. It was the first hit.  I find that site useful when needed to research file extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is really such thing as .dat file format. It's short for "data," and different applications just put in some proprietary stuff in it and call it ".dat." You can read up on fstream classes to do file IO in C++. See [Input/Output with files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

What you then do is make up your own file format. For example, first 4 byte is int that indicates the number of blocks in the .dat and for each block, you have 4 byte indicating the length of each block, 4 byte indicating the type of the block, the variable length data itself .. something like that.

Comment: I've reviewed the information given and your answer was correct, straight forward and first of the answers I felt were of this quality.

I obviously did not search the right keywords, as I would have found a similar and very informative post on stackoverflow itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

DAT obviously stands for data, and there is no real or de facto standard on what that extension actually refers to.  Your decisions on the best file formats should be based on technical considerations, not pointless attempts at security through obscurity.

Answer (score 1):

Professional games use a technique where they put all the needed resources (models, textures, sounds, ai, config, etc) zipped/packed into a single file thus making it faster to manage, harder to change (some even make use of a virtual filing system from what's inside the data file). Now, for what's inside the file is different depending on the needs of the game and the data structures that you use.

If you're just starting into gamedev,  i recommend you stick with keeping all you assets separate and don't bother too much about packing them into a single file.

Now if you really want to start using a packed format here's a good pointer:
[Creating a PAK File Format](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/pak/)

Comment: While I do believe this is also a correct answer, eed3si9n was the first to address something similar. Thank you for the answer, either way.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a link](http://www.moviecodec.com/file-types/dat-format-2325/) which claims that **.dat** is a movie format, 'DAT' being short for Digital Audio Tape.

I'm not sure I believe the link, but I *do* remember something about a Microsoft supported format called DAT, from long ago, when I used an earlier version of Windows.

It makes more sense as a logical extension for a DATA file of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

.dat, as others have said, is literally just a data file.  In reality, the file extension means nothing other than association with a program.  For example, I could make a word processor that saves all the documents with the .mp3 file extension.  These files wouldn't be playable in any media software, but the software might try.  File extensions are used to help programs know what types of files they can and cannot open--however those rules don't have to be followed.

Anyway, you can dump any sort of information to a file.  Programmers/software writers will often choose .dat as the extension of that file because it has become the standard to signify 'this file just holds a ton of data' and that the data doesn't necessarily hold any standardized headers, footers, or formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A dat file could really contain anything. It might be as simple as a zip archive with the extension changed, or it could be a completely custom file type. If you're just starting out, you probably don't want to write your own file format, although doing so can be fun and educational. If you want to encapsulate your data files into some kind of container, you should probably go with a zip, paq, or maybe tar.gz.